# How to delete a specific child from firebase realtime database using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

i'm creating a game which stores it data in firebase database. Suppose When i touch a key it sets left:1 in database. How can i delete this left:1 when i remove the touch from that key.

The below code shows how i set left:1 in database.

```
document.getElementById('moveleft').addEventListener('touchstart',()=>{
        var left1 = left + 1;
        console.log(left1);

            var totalleft = firebase.database().ref('total left');

            totalleft.push({
                'left':left1
            });
            });
```

How can i delete this child(left) from the database when i remove the touch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete a node from the database you'll need to have a reference to that node. The easiest way to do this, is to keep the reference in a variable in the `touchstart` handler:

```
var touchRef;
document.getElementById('moveleft').addEventListener('touchstart',()=>{

    var left1 = left + 1;
    console.log(left1);

    var totalleft = firebase.database().ref('total left');

    touchRef = totalleft.push({
        'left':left1
    });
});
```

And then in `touchend` handler you can use the reference to remove the nde:

```
document.getElementById('moveleft').addEventListener('touchend',()=>{
    touchRef.remove()
})
```